# Valid Email in ActionScript 3

Tags: regex, flash, actionscript-3, email-validation, contact-form

i am using

```
var emailExpression:RegExp = /^[a-z][\w.-]+@\w[\w.-]+\.[\w.-]*[a-z][a-z]$/i;
```

for validation check in a contact form in ActionScript3.

---

The problem is that if the email submitted starts with a numeric character then it is rejected.
for example the email 45yah.yah@yahoo.com is rejected but the mail yah45.yah@yahoo.com is acceptable.

what should i change?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var emailExpression:RegExp = /^[\w.-]+@\w[\w.-]+\.[\w.-]*[a-z][a-z]$/i;
```

BTW, did you try [this](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/validators/EmailValidator.html)?

Comment: Is that for Flex only? Could you provide an example of how to use the built in emailValidator?

Answer (score 1):

you might also find http://gskinner.com/RegExr/ useful for creating regexp solutions to stuff like this

Answer (score 0):

Here is one that does not fail with q.com email addresses.

```
function isValidEmail(email:String):Boolean {
    var emailExpression:RegExp = /^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/i;
    return emailExpression.test(email);
}
```