# How to check if a textbox contains a specific string or not?

Tags: actionscript-3

I have an input textfield named "textbox" and a button named "submit".I also have two text messages "mc_error" and "form_submitted" which are not visible from the beginning. Upon clicking the button, I want it to check if the textfield contains "@" in it. I have tried the below code that uses indexOf but it always returns the value -1 and therefore upon execution always "mc_error" becomes visible.

```
var str:String = textbox.text;
submit.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fl_MouseClickHandler);
mc_error.visible = false;
form_submitted.visible = false;

function fl_MouseClickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
{
  var index:int = str.indexOf("@");
  if(index == -1)
  {
      mc_error.visible=true;
  }
  else
  {
      form_submitted.visible=true;
  }

}
```

Would be grateful if got some immediate answers as i need it working in 2 days.Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you set variable **before** user inputs anything there and it is always "". Just don't use that variable (or read it in the function body as shown below) and it will be fine.

```
function fl_MouseClickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    var str:String = textbox.text;
    var index:int = str.indexOf("@");

    if(index == -1)
    {
        mc_error.visible=true;
    }
    else
    {
        form_submitted.visible=true;
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you. That was it. :-)

Comment: On a different topic. How can i check whether there is something before and after the "@" within the textbox? Basically I'm making a form where a user has to input his email address. Would be great if u could answer this too.

Comment: @AkashChoudhary http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5713603/valid-email-in-actionscript-3